# Como converter os campos em uma linha com string?

Tags: c#

Segue o código:

**Model:**

```
public class Usuario
{
   public string Campo1 { get; set; }
   public string Campo2 { get; set; }
   public string Campo3 { get; set; }
   public string Campo4 { get; set; }
   public string Campo5 { get; set; }
   public string Campo6 { get; set; }
   public string Campo7 { get; set; }
   public string Campo8 { get; set; }
   public string Campo9 { get; set; }
   public string Campo10 { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
var teste = new Usuario();
string texto = ""+teste.Campo1+ teste.Campo2+ etc"";
```

Como pode ver o código acima, existe maneira mais fácil sem ficar digitado `teste`? Ou seja, só digitar `teste` que já preenche todos os campos com seu valor. Porque amanhã posso ter mais de 100 campos.

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considerando que o número de campos vai aumentar, use [*Reflection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string retorno = "";
    foreach (var campo in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
    {
        retorno += " " + campo.GetValue(this, null);
    }

   return retorno;
}
```

O que eu faria é definir uma classe ancestral com o método:

```
public abstract class Basica 
{
   public override string ToString()
   {
        string retorno = "";
        foreach (var campo in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
        {
            retorno += " " + campo.GetValue(this, null);
        }

       return retorno;
   }
}
```

`Usuario` herdar:

```
public class Usuario : Basica
{
   public string Campo1 { get; set; }
   public string Campo2 { get; set; }
   public string Campo3 { get; set; }
   public string Campo4 { get; set; }
   public string Campo5 { get; set; }
   public string Campo6 { get; set; }
   public string Campo7 { get; set; }
   public string Campo8 { get; set; }
   public string Campo9 { get; set; }
   public string Campo10 { get; set; }
}
```

E um teste:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var usuario = new Usuario 
        {
            Campo1 = "Teste1",
            Campo2 = "Teste2",
            Campo3 = "Teste3",
            Campo4 = "Teste4"
        };
        Console.WriteLine(usuario.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hi6mkv).

Comment: Resolveu problema aqui, obrigado Cigano Morrisson Mendez

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar um método ou propriedade no Model. Por exemplo:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Campo1{ get; set; }
    public string Campo2{ get; set; }
    public string Campo3{ get; set; }
    public string Campo4{ get; set; }
    //etc.

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Campo1 + Campo2 + Campo3 + Campo4; // +etc.
    }
}
```

E no controller:

```
var teste = new Usuario();
string texto = teste.ToString();
```

Eu sobrecarreguei o método ToString do tipo, mas você também pode criar um método novo ao invés disso.

Answer (score 5):

Dá pra fazer com [*reflection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx). Você precisa tomar cuidado porque, geralmente, *reflection* deixa a execução bem mais demorada.

Veja um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Usuario { Campo1 = "teste", Campo2 = "teste 2" };

        Type type = obj .GetType();

        var texto = "";
        foreach(var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}={prop.GetValue(obj, null)}");
            texto += prop.GetValue(obj, null) + " ";
        }
    }
}

public class Usuario
{
    public string Campo1 { get; set; }
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }
    public string Campo3 { get; set; }
    public string Campo4 { get; set; }
    public string Campo5 { get; set; }
    public string Campo6 { get; set; }
    public string Campo7 { get; set; }
    public string Campo8 { get; set; }
    public string Campo9 { get; set; }
    public string Campo10 { get; set; }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PqkQmK)

Comment: Interessante a sua resposta, obrigado jbueno.

Answer (score 3):

usa o System.Reflection.PropertyInfo

sobrecarrega o ToString() como Renan postou, mas dessa forma:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string retorno = "";
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pr in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (pr.CanRead)
        {
           object valor = pr.GetValue(this, null);
           retorno += pr.Name +": "+ (valor == null ? "" : valor.ToString()) + ", ";
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

aí o resultado será:

```
var teste = new Usuario();
string texto = teste.ToString();
//Campo1: Valor, Campo2: Valor, Campo3: Valor, ...
```